# How to unit test an OSGi bundle from another OSGi bundle

Tags: unit-testing, osgi

I'm new in OSGi and I have some trouble with unit test. I've an OSGi bundle that exports some services, installed on a Jboss Fuse. I have to create a new OSGi bundle that unit tests the first bundle's services. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A best practice for OSGi units tests is to use [pax exam](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXEXAM4/Pax+Exam).
It allows to setup a container so it loads your bundles under test. Then you can write junit tests that get the services injected and can work on the services.

Comment: I've read about pax exam. Maybe I'm yet very far from understand completely how OSGi works. After some trial with pax exam I don't know how to use it. When I install on jboss fuse a bundle that uses pax exam, is returned an error because missing package org.ops4j.pax.exam.

Comment: When using pax exam you would not install the bundle into fuse. Instead you let pax exam pull up the fuse container which is karaf based. So look into the karaf examples of pax exam.